# Deactivate form inputs in Flask-Restplus Swagger UI

Tags: python, flask, swagger-ui, flask-restplus

I'm looking for a way to deactivate the **form inputs** and **try button** generated for each endpoint in the **Flask-Restplus Swagger UI**. I haven't found any info in the documentation so I thought I would ask. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method in Flask-RESTPlus as noted in [how to customize the UI?](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/130), but you should be able to achieve what you are looking for by:

- Provide your own Swagger UI [custom view function](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swagger.html#swagger-ui)
- Use a custom plugin to disable Try button as described in [How to disable 'Try it out' in 3.x](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3725)
- You might find [How to remove Authorize and Try it Out](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3314) buttons also useful